# SSIS Derived Column IS NOT NULL with Or expression

Tags: ssis, null, derived

I need assistance writing an Derived Column expression that meets this criteria.

IF ([Name of Job] is  "Accenture Leadership" OR "Senior Executive") AND [Pay scale Group] IS NOT NULL THEN  [Pay scale Group] ELSE [Name of Job].

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

Try this:`([Name of Job] == "Accenture Leadership" ||[Name of Job] == "Senior Executive") && ISNULL([Pay scale Group]) == FALSE ? [Pay scale Group] : [Name of Job]`

[reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141680.aspx)